# Varbinary Extraction to File

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to extract my varbinary data to it's original format and save it to a file. Here's what I have so far and it doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't create the files.

```
DECLARE @DocumentName varchar(500) = 'C:\' + @LicenseNumber + '\' + @FileType 
    + '\' + convert(nvarchar(MAX), @FileDate, 21) + ' ' + @LicenseNumber 
    + ' ' + @FileTypeCode + ' ' + @Quarter + @FileExtension 

EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'               
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @DocumentData         
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @DocumentName, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'              
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
```

Is there anything wrong here that anyone can see?

Comment: Maybe not the problem. But double check the actual file name you generate and make sure the path exists and is writable. Don't see anything inherently wrong in your code.

Comment: If the directory and filename doesn't exist, shouldn't it just create them?

Comment: Depends upon how it is written internally. Why not set @document name to a known valid directory and see if it works then.

Comment: I just tested locally. Without valid existing directory -- nothing happens. With valid directory, it creates the file.

Comment: I just manually created the local folders and it still did not create the files.

Comment: The code you supplied is correct. Have you printed your document name to confirm it was as expected? Have you enabled OLE Automation for the sp_AOMethod function? (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191188.aspx) - I know you should get error message if OLE is not enabled, but just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I printed the name and it's exactly how I need it. I was getting execution permission denide on the sp_OA..., but the administrator gave my stored proceedure rights and now I don't get the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I think that would break this script is the full path being larger than 500 characters and being truncated when assigned to @DocumentName.

Comment: It would never get close to 500 characters. 100 maybe.

Comment: Can you put a `PRINT @DocumentName` to see if the path is what you want?

Comment: I did and it displays the dircetory structure and file that I want.

Comment: Have you checked that the SQL-Server service process is granted the required permissions? Also ASODB.Stream won't create the directory structure for you. Did you check that too?

Comment: I manually created the directories and ran this locally. Why would there be any permissions?

Comment: OK, only thing I can think of to help is to enable tracing on the OLE call. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926098 (for ole tracing in general including the logging info) and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926098 for tracing from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the DECLARE @DocumentName varchar(500) = 'C:\', the 'C:\' portion needs to be on the server that you are running the script from. Once I changed it to the server name instead of c:\, it worked fine. Sometimes its the little things that mess up a whole day. :-)